# Get autodiscovery links with Universal feed parser (feedparser)

Tags: python, rss, feedparser, autodiscovery

I just started to use feedparser and wonder if there was any way to get a list of autodiscovery links.

Thanks in advance.
Massimo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

feedparser can't do it on it's own, but [feedfinder2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedfinder2) can:

```
from feedfinder2 import find_feeds
import feedparser

feeds = find_feeds('http://timbroder.com')

feeds
#[u'http://feeds.feedburner.com/timbroder']

d = feedparser.parse(feeds[0])
d['feed']['title']
#u'timbroder.com'
```